# .css problems between firefox/ie/chrome/Safari

Tags: css, firefox, google-chrome, webkit, gallery

I'm working on building a website, and everything is pretty much done, but I'm running into issues that, from what I've read here, are a result of webkit in firefox and ie.

Here is one of the pages that is having problems:

http://prdesignstudio.com/Seattle.html

When you load it in Chrome or safari it works fine, the images are reflected at the bottom, and there are no images on a lower row.  When you open it in Firefox or ie, on the other hand, there are no reflections, and the last image in the set is on a lower row.  Another thing that's odd is that the problem doesn't occur on every page, and it also doesn't seem to be based on the number of images in the gallery.  (The different pages can be found by clicking on portfolio)

Anyone know how to fix this?  Also, if fixing it requires me to remove the webkit portions of the .css, does anyone know of something else I can do to get the reflections?  They're not necessary, but I like them XD

All the page's code can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/2DvSP/

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for the images appearing on a lower row and the occurance of this on not all but some pages, you have inline styles set

```
div calss="container" style="width: 2080px;"
```

If you increase the width, this problems does not happen in FF4.01 and IE9.

Comment: @JAA149 That sounds like a simple fix, but I cannot find that code tidbit.  Which portion of the code did you find that in?

Comment: html body div#fp_gallery.fp_gallery div#outer_container div#thumbScroller div.container

Comment: @JAA149 I'm looking at Seattle.html and not seeing it, Sorry if I'm missing it, but all I see there is:<div class="container">   I also looked through the css and saw no definition of thumbscroller width.

Comment: Look at it in Firefox with Firebug. In the right hand under style you will find element.style {
    left: -376.25px;
    width: 2080px;
}

Comment: @JAA149 well, I did this:  <div class="container" style="width: 5000px;">  but I'm still having the problem with the last image showing up on a lower line.  That's not something I've been defining as part of the code, that's been determining the width based on the number of images in the gallery.

Comment: Thats strange. I changed width to 3000px and it fixes the problem as follows http://i51.tinypic.com/20t3xgx.jpg

Comment: @JAA149 Somewhere in the gallery coding it's automatically resizing it, which is what adding the width style didn't fix it.  Off to look for where that is...

Comment: @JAA149 Alright, found it.  Now, any ideas how to add reflections without webkit?  lol   Thanks for all the help.

Comment: You have to work extra for cross borwser comptability. Maybe this will help you. I have not tried it myslef. Post back if it works http://www.digitalia.be/software/reflectionjs-for-jquery